# Cannot connect to local database

Tags: mysql, apache

I have apache and mysql set up on my local machine (Mac).

Whenever I go to any of my local sites I get the "Error establishing a database connection" whenever anything mySql related happens.

It was working perfectly yesterday, but when I started my computer today it is not.

I can login to mysql on the terminal and that all works fine, I can view database and run queries in the terminal. Look at all my table etc.

I've tried restarting apache.

Anyone know what's up? This is worrying.

UPDATE...

It is somthing in my php.ini file, if I restore the default one it all works fine and dandy again. What in there could be doing it?

Comment: We would need more data, logs perhaps

Comment: What changes did you make to your `php.ini` file? What settings did you change, and what did you change them to? A list of the options with default & new values would help immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in php.ini, I needed to set:

mysql.default_socket = /path_to_file/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer to the specific question, but it is rather a suggesting IF you are just doing development on your box. I would suggest skipping all the configurations and go with [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

Comment: Naaa mamp messes with stuff and isn't as elegant, also I have rails running sometimes which might interfere with it.